# Coefficients nature in a quadratic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b+c < 0$ and the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$ has imaginary roots then is $a$ and $c$ greater than or less than $0$?

Comment: And always do some quick tests to ensure your answer is plausible: gandraxa.com/using_the_quadratic_formula.xml

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. The sign of $a$ is determined by the shape of $\hspace{2mm}f(x)$, while the value of $c$ is determined by $f(0) = c$. $\hspace{2mm}f(1) = a+b+c$ gives a hint about the shape of $f(x)$.

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Notice that $a+b+c<0$ implies $f(1) < 0$. Put this with the fact that $\hspace{2mm}f(x)$ only has imaginary roots, we know $f(x)<0$ is true for all $x$, and hence $a<0$. This also gives us $c=f(0)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

If the trinomial has no real root, $f(0)=c,f(1)=a+b+c$ have necessarily the same sign as $a$.